# Error when run bitnami postgres container

Tags: postgresql, docker, bitnami

it's my first time with docker. I have created a docker container from a bitnami image with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM bitnami/postgresql:14.1.0
MAINTAINER <whatever>

ADD --chown=1001:1001 main /bitnami/postgresql/data
```

where `main` is  a copy of my postgresql database `/var/lib/postgresql/data`

When I try to run the container in this way:

`docker run -d --name database -p 5432:5432 -e ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes mypostgres`

I get the following error, does anyone know what it is and how to fix it.

```
postgresql 15:39:28.09 
postgresql 15:39:28.09 Welcome to the Bitnami postgresql container
postgresql 15:39:28.09 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-postgresql
postgresql 15:39:28.09 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-postgresql/issues
postgresql 15:39:28.09 
postgresql 15:39:28.12 INFO  ==> ** Starting PostgreSQL setup **
postgresql 15:39:28.16 INFO  ==> Validating settings in POSTGRESQL_* env vars..
postgresql 15:39:28.17 WARN  ==> You set the environment variable ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes. For safety reasons, do not use this flag in a production environment.
postgresql 15:39:28.18 INFO  ==> Loading custom pre-init scripts...
postgresql 15:39:28.18 INFO  ==> Initializing PostgreSQL database...
postgresql 15:39:28.21 INFO  ==> pg_hba.conf file not detected. Generating it...
postgresql 15:39:28.22 INFO  ==> Generating local authentication configuration
postgresql 15:39:28.23 INFO  ==> Deploying PostgreSQL with persisted data...
postgresql 15:39:28.25 INFO  ==> Configuring replication parameters
postgresql 15:39:28.30 INFO  ==> Configuring fsync
postgresql 15:39:28.34 INFO  ==> Loading custom scripts...
postgresql 15:39:28.34 INFO  ==> Enabling remote connections
postgresql 15:39:28.37 INFO  ==> ** PostgreSQL setup finished! **

postgresql 15:39:28.41 INFO  ==> ** Starting PostgreSQL **
2021-12-14 15:39:28.454 GMT [1] LOG:  pgaudit extension initialized
2021-12-14 15:39:28.462 GMT [1] FATAL:  could not open directory "pg_notify": No such file or directory
2021-12-14 15:39:28.463 GMT [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Comment: Where does the image `mypostgres` come from?  Can you provide its Dockerfile, and any other details for a [mcve]?

Comment: Do you really need `ADD` in a custom image? You could mount a volume for a dump during `docker run`